# How to use numbers from a list as argument in random.randint(x, y) python

Tags: python-3.x, random

x = random.randint(1, 100)
y = random.randint(1, 100)

myList = [x, y]
newNumber = random.randint(x, y)

but when...

myList = [(nsmallest(2, guesses, key=lambda x: abs(x-number)))]

I don't know what the numbers are, and how to use them as arguments (x, y) to determine the newNumber

Answer (score 0):

["Unpacking Argument Lists"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
random.randint(*myList)
```